Can't boot Windows after installing dual boot Ubuntu
I installed dual boot Ubuntu according to the tutorial here.
The installation was a success, but after restarting my computer it went straight to Ubuntu.
I tried switching to Windows using the boot menu, but no matter what option I chose it went to Ubuntu.

I checked the Disks app, and Windows is still there.

I tried to mount it, but an error message that I don't understand appeared.


This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If Windows is on MBR(msdos) drie, then it is installed in old BIOS/MBR configuration. Systems since 2012 are UEFI as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI with gpt partitioning for new installs. If you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode on same drive you need to fix Windows boot flag and reinstall Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Since only one MBR, you need both Windows repair/recovery drive & Ubuntu live installer to regularly update MBR when Windows needs fixes as grub only boots working Windows.
